# Error to post nativescript form data using web api2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, nativescript, angular7

While posting form data in nativescript-angular, I am getting below error
originalStack: Error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused\n    at new ZoneAwareError

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript's Http Client [doesn't support FormData](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/59). You will have to either use JSON request Or use [nativescript-http-formdata](https://github.com/dotnetdreamer/nativescript-http-formdata) plugin to send data.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-http-formdata
```

**Note:** If you use the plugin, you would loose the luxury of using Angular's HttpClient & features like interceptors etc.,